# resizing a ImageIcon in a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am creating a JButton which includes a specific ImageIcon. The main issue is that the original icon size is much bigger than the button size. As result when the button is displayed, only part of the icon can be seen. What is the method that "resize" an ImageIcon i n order to make it fit inside a JButton?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
   Image img = icon.getImage() ;  
   Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;  
   icon = new ImageIcon( newimg );
```

from http://www.coderanch.com/t/331731/GUI/java/Resize-ImageIcon

Answer (score 1):

I would try to override the `getIcon()` method of `JButton`, and resize the `super.getIcon()`. (Or, redefining the lnf for that button.)

Answer (score 0):

I used [this class](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/)

I included the code from "get the code" (at the bottom) as another class in my project. Be sure to change the package name if you want it to work.