# java: how to resize a frame containg image

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, netbeans-7

I have created one frame and displaying an image into frame. but I am unable set the size of a frame. As i have tried following code, but its giving me the part of image i have set, Not the whole image. Please help me to re-size the image.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");
frame.setSize(200,200);
int frameWidth = 200;
int frameHeight = 200;
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setBounds((int) screenSize.getWidth() - frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the .setSize() method with different parameters?

Comment: I have tried the .setSize(height,width) method only. Is there any other method other than this?

Comment: How about posting the entire application, so we can see how you add the image etc. We might be able to spot something that could help you?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856480/resizing-a-imageicon-in-a-jbutton) answer might help you.

Comment: public void Capture()
{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("F:\\POSTERS\\Roses\\P100.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
      {
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
      }
    });

Comment: JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    int frameWidth = 150;
    int frameHeight = 300;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setBounds((int) screenSize.getWidth() - frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
capture mathod is called on button click.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing [absolute positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) and usage of [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).
When you call `setSize()` or `setBounds()`, you are using absolute layout, ie, you manage manually the size and location of your components.

When you call `pack()`, you delegate the sizing and positioning to the LayoutManagers of the component inside your frame. LayoutManager's position and size the components based on their preferred/minimum/maximum size and constraints. See all about LayoutManager's [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

I would recommend to rely on LayoutManagers because it works better across different platforms and your code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

```
package test.t100.t004;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageSizedGUI {

    ImageSizedGUI(Image image) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Image");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // either this, or..
        f.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(label));

        f.pack();
        // ..this, but could produce undesirable results for images 
        // that are larger than screen size!
        // f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String address = (args.length>0 ? args[0] :
                "http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg");
        URL url = new URL(address);
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new ImageSizedGUI(image);
            }
        });
    }
}
```