# resize ImageIcon within JPanel where file is retrieved from a folder

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

I wish to resize an ImageIcon within a JPanel, and I know there are suggestions everywhere, where it does not work for the following no matter how I edit it. The following is one of the many attempts, which i find closest to my aim.

With courtesy from: [resizing a ImageIcon in a JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856480/resizing-a-imageicon-in-a-jbutton)

How can i rectify my code?

```
        JLabel lblFoodPicUrl = new JLabel();
        lblFoodPicUrl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (50,50));
        lblFoodPicUrl.setIcon (new ImageIcon (PlaceOrder.class.getResource("/Pictures/" + food_Pic_Url + ".jpg")));
        lblFoodPicUrl.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.CENTER);


        Image img = (Image) lblFoodPicUrl.getIcon();
        Image newing = img.getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        lblFoodPicUrl = new ImageIcon (newing);
```

Comment: `lblFoodPicUrl = new ImageIcon (newing);` what this code is supposed to do ?

Comment: thank you, the reference i got from left it this way. So i am trying to implement the contributor's suggestion into mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. but you fixed your label and imageicon size. so it is not bother about jpanel size.

```
    JLabel lblFoodPicUrl = new JLabel();
    lblFoodPicUrl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    lblFoodPicUrl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("your path")));
    lblFoodPicUrl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(lblFoodPicUrl.getIcon().getIconWidth(), lblFoodPicUrl.getIcon().getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
    lblFoodPicUrl.getIcon().paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
    Image newing = img.getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    lblFoodPicUrl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newing));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It should dynamically resize the icon if the size of the label ever changes.